# Graph API filter working on GraphExplorer however not working on SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

How come this is working https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks?filter=tolower(name) eq 'my notebook'

[Screenshot from Graph Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCbxA.png)

and when I try to code the same in C#, I am getting the below error
Code: BadRequest
Message: Invalid filter clause
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date: 2020-09-02T20:01:24

I'm using the below code.

var NoteBook = await GraphClient.Me.Onenote.Notebooks.Request().Filter($"name eq 'My Notebook'").GetAsync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks?filter=tolower(name) eq 'my notebook'`. You missed a `$` before `filter=xxx`.

The correct one should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks?$filter=tolower(displayName) eq 'my notebook'`.

There is not a property named `name`. You can get the result because the filter doesn't take effect. You list all the notebooks. The correct one is `displayName`.

But in SDK there is not an attribute `name` defined in notebook class. That's why you get the error while using SDK.

In SDK you should use this code:

```
var NoteBook = await graphClient.Me.Onenote.Notebooks.Request().Filter($"displayName eq 'My Notebook'").GetAsync();
```